# What accounts for the discrepancy between the memory use shown when hovering on the Chrome tab, and the heap size?

Tags: google-chrome, memory

Chrome tabs now show active memory used by the tab when you hover on the tab title; see [here](https://medium.com/@addyosmani/chrome-now-shows-each-active-tabs-memory-usage-4f74876538e6) for the details.

Chrome also allows us to get more details on the memory use in the Memory panel of Devtools, where a (constantly updated) JS heap size is provided. I can also take a heap snapshot from right there in the Memory panel, and I can see the size of the heap snapshot.

I found that the JS heap size and the heap snapshot size are within the same ballpark of each other, but the active memory use by the tab is (usually) *significantly* higher.

For instance, on https://example.com/, in one particular load, I got a tab memory use of 23.8 MB:

[image: example.com tab memory use]

For comparison, the JS heap size is 1.1 MB (see bottom):

[image: JS heap size on example.com]

The snapshot size is also 1.1 MB (see left column)

[image: JS heap snapshot for example.com]

For context, example.com is an extremely small page, about 1 KB in size, and it renders on a single screen with no scrolling needed (see first screenshot above).

I've also noticed that tab memory use can adjust down a little bit under memory pressure (e.g., if I open a lot of tabs) or backgrounding (e.g., I tab away from the tab for some tme) but I have rarely seen it come down all the way to match the heap size or heap snapshot size.

So, what causes the greater active tab memory use, how can we get better insight into what aspects of the page structure and content are contributing to it, and could the active tab memory use that is *over and above* the heap size cause out-of-memory issues?

NOTE: I learned from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76127296/debugging-a-ios-safari-crash-a-problem-repeatedly-occurred that Safari gives more information on memory use related to rendering/painting through its Layers panel, but I don't see any information on memory use in the equivalent Layers panel in Chrome Devtools.

Comment: Is there even any JavaScript in this page? However, there's content and styles and maybe fonts and stuff.

Comment: The website doesn't have any inline JS or script JS, but Chrome does have a bunch of JS data and functions based on the general functionality it offers. (For instance, `window.performance.getEntries()` will return the network call information).

Comment: The initial usage for the page of this question is 49.2 Mb. Interestingly, a refresh bumps it to 58 Mb. Variations on consumption may occur on other SE tabs/windows, tab duplication or moving to new window etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

The "Memory Usage" is the full memory used by the browser engine to render that tab (the process itself together with any loaded html, css, images, scripts ...). The "JS Heap" is only the space reserved for objects and functions by the JS engine.

### Complete answer

In modern browsers, a web page is rendered by a [browser engine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_engine), which for chromium is called [blink](https://www.chromium.org/blink/) and is written in C++.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)):

> Blink engine has the following components:
>
> - DOM, HTML DOM and CSS rendering engines
> - Web IDL implementation
> - Skia Graphics engine — makes calls to an underlying
>   Graphics Library (like OpenGL, Vulkan, DirectX etc) which depends on
>   the platform
> - V8 JavaScript engine

The JS Heap is created only by the "V8 Javascript" part of the browser engine. Also note that the Heap is

> used to store objects and functions in JavaScript. The engine doesn’t allocate a fixed amount of memory. Instead, it allocates more space as required. ([source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-management-in-javascript/))

So, the JS Heap does not contain any of the code necessary to make neither the JS engine nor the complete browser engine do its job.

Moreover, given that chromium (at least on desktop) implements tab isolation, [as described here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/process_model_and_site_isolation.md#Full-Site-Isolation-site_per_process) (i.e. one separate process per tab, no shared resources), for each new tab opened, (a large part of) the whole browser engine needs to be loaded separately into memory. As the developers write:

> For stability, putting web site instances in separate processes limits the impact of a renderer process crash or hang, allowing other content to continue working. For performance, this allows different web site instances to run in parallel with better responsiveness, at the cost of some memory overhead for each process.

There is a lot more to rendering webpages, as you can read [for example here,](https://www.zachgollwitzer.com/posts/how-browser-loads-parses-renders-webpage) but to keep it simple, the "memory used per tab" includes:

- the browser engine (or a significant subset of it)
- the web page itself and any loaded assets (css, images, videos, scripts, ...)
- the JS Heap
- the JS Stack ([see here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-management-in-javascript/))
- other stuff needed for this specific process

So the JS Heap is just a small bit of it all. It is treated separately in the console as it can be responsible for memory leaks, especially since "it allocates more space than what is required."

[Further reading on the JS Heap Profiler](https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art038)

### EDIT

To get a more complete picture of what is going on, you'll need to deep-dive into how to use the developer tools, which I would do [using the official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/).

The JS Heap is the part that can be responsible for memory leaks, but to gain insights to various performance issues, you'll have to work through the console and the performance tabs first.

However, since you are using MacOS, you might try Safari's "more complete memory usage" outline which you mention. Be aware though that Safari uses a different browser engine, Webkit, which will behave differently from chrome.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful! I'd love if you can share any thoughts on these other aspects of the question: "how can we get better insight into what aspects of the page structure and content are contributing to it, and could the active tab memory use that is over and above the heap size cause out-of-memory issues?"

Comment: I also added this para to the original question; getting the sort of information for Chrome is part of what I'm looking for:

"NOTE: I learned from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76127296/debugging-a-ios-safari-crash-a-problem-repeatedly-occurred that Safari gives more information on memory use related to rendering/painting through its Layers panel, but I don't see any information on memory use in the equivalent Layers panel in Chrome Devtools."

Comment: @VipulNaik See my edit. // About: "how can we get better insight into what aspects of the page structure and content are contributing to it, and could the active tab memory use that is over and above the heap size cause out-of-memory issues?"  --> look at the assets the page loads by default. And look at how the JS Heap grows with user interaction. See the "further reading" link above.

Comment: @VipulNaik You'll have to read through the various links I inserted to gain more insight. This is not the place for a full-fledged tutorial. If you have more specific questions, stackoverflow might be the better place to ask.

Comment: Ok thanks. It seems from what you're saying that even though the JS heap would *normally* account for only a small fraction of memory use, it's almost always the culprit when it comes to running out of memory? So, Chrome not showing a breakdown of memory use outside of the JS heap isn't a problem for debugging crashes? In Safari (as indicated in the linked Stack Overflow answer) there are cases where memory use by Layers (rendering/painting) is the thing that causes pages to crash and reload; I anecdotally think the same may be going on with Chrome, but Chrome doesn't show Layers memory use.

Comment: @VipulNaik  This is going well beyond the scope of your original question. However, I've found an article which will help you. You can do a complete memory analysis from within chrome. See here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/memory-problems/     There's also another interesting oversight (but it's behind a paywall): https://medium.com/@addyosmani/chrome-now-shows-each-active-tabs-memory-usage-4f74876538e6

Comment: Thanks! I looked at both articles. The first one seems to be guidance associated with an older version of Chrome, and for the relevant portion for me (the parts about memory use *outside* the JavaScript heap), the methods referenced in that doc don't work. The second article was already linked from my original question, and I had tried the methods in it, but they showed either nothing or memory use in the ballpark of 200 KB, which was still way less than the ~20MB+ that Chrome showed for the tab use.

Answer (score 2):

Each tab is a separate Chrome process, so I examined in Task Manager
the multiple processes that are started by Chrome.
I then found one `chrome.exe` process that uses a very similar amount
of memory to the number in the hover message.

I think that the explanation is that the amount you see in the message
is the total memory used by Chrome to display the tab.
This includes not only the JS cache, but the entire process that's
displaying the tab.

As Windows only keeps one copy of the code part in `chrome.exe` in
memory, which is shared by all the `chrome.exe` processes, this
amount includes only data and stack. The 1.1 MB JavaScript stack
that you see is only a part of this amount.

The displayed amount is a bit larger than the amount in Task Manager.
This can be explained by the Active Private Working Space I show in
Task Manager not including everything that Chrome is using for the tab.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful! I use Mac OS rather than Windows, but I think the equivalent is true there as well (I have to look in Activity Monitor rather than Task Manager).

Comment: Chrome is the same in all operating systems. What changes is the interface to the system, and the system libraries that are used. In this way, Chrome keeps the native look in every system to which it's ported.

Comment: I noticed that Chrome also has its own Task Manager (at least on Macs) that is kinda like the Windows Task Manager except it's limited to the processes within Chrome. This can be accessed using `More Tools > Task Manager`.